# Increasing molecular bond strength as Strengthening Magic

Tags: biology, magic, strength

Let's say a wild mage appears (again!) and uses magic to increase the molecular bond strength of the muscles, bones and tendons of a random villager. Supposing their musculature, and other tissues, stays the same, aside from the magical effect, of course, would this provoke an increase on overall strength?

Would it translate in increase speed, lifting power, etc? If the buff is enduring or even permanent, how would it relate to the necessary food intake?

Comment: Holy unintended consequences batman!  From a harder science point of view: Depending on how large the change The bodies, biochemistry would no longer correctly function with the affected tissues. It could quite probably change the shape of those tissues to non functional.

Comment: Screwing with the physics of atomic bonds (quantum state transition energies, at base what we're talking about) tends to result in things like immediate death, or at worst, the impossibility of the universe coming into being in the first place. But don't let that put you off.

Comment: Well, It's not something that happens naturally, and the increase in molecular strength can be temporary. A short effect spell would mess everything up permanently? Aside that, it could become a interesting way to kill someone or even a cruel punishment depending on how painful it can be.

Comment: It sounds as if you are going to need to handwave the  details, otherwise we're talking lack of any strength or movement as you might intend. At this point, giving you the biological details of the sort of (millions of) energy transitions within muscles is irrelevant, true to say, without "normal" chemistry between atoms, the whole thing can get broken pretty fast. If ultimately it's all about the story, then handwave the science.

Comment: I appreciate that you try to bring up your own ideas. I don't want to dissuade you from asking more of your creative solutions. Still, have you considered just asking what you could possibly to with a single magic spell which influences the real world to an extent that someone gets super strength? Or just writing in the story "becauae I say so"?

Comment: Ah, the thing is, I want to keep the handwavium to a minimum, not inexistent, but as little as I can, preferably to things like the origin and basest function of a magic system, building from the ground up. Of course, some of the effects will have to happen 'because yes' but the least the better.

Comment: An analogy: take a car. In a car, there are parts that benefit from being strong, and strongly affixed to each other; the less flexing and slippage, the more efficient the car is. But there are also parts that need to be lubricated, to slide past each other easily. And the tires and suspension can't be rigid, they need to bend and flex. And the gasoline needs to burn. If every material in your car was ultra-strong and rigid, your car would be useless. And humans are way, way more complicated than cars.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

The bond in the muscles might strengthen, as well as in the bones and such, but as the amount of muscles stays the same the person won't be able to lift more or move faster. Food intake and such won't change in that regard. An argument could be made for more compressive or shearing strength, but...

**No**

Increasing the molecular bonds can have unintended side-effects. The molecules react the way they do in part because of the molecular bond being that strength. Increasing it can make all the properties change. They might not be molecules that can make up bones, muscles and tendons anymore, making them most likely less suitable for their task.